# Determine the number of revolutions the normal to a curve makes as it moves along a curve in three dimensions?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Given a point on a 3D curve, how many full revolutions does the normal to the curve at the point make as the point moves over the curve? Assume the point stops when it reaches the place where it started.

I've researched torsion on wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_of_a_curve ) but I'm not sure that is correct, and my tests don't give full multiples of 2pi leading me to believe I've got something wrong. I've also tried to understand Frenet–Serret formulas, with not much success.

My math skills are okay up through beginning calculus (assuming a typical American mathematics curriculum), but are rather rusty. I'm looking to answer this question as I have an idea related to knots that may depend on the answer to this question.

Either an exact solution or algorithm for approximating a solution would be very helpful, or even just a pointer in the right direction.

This is my first question on StackExchange, so if I've made any missteps, please let me know (and be gentle ;-)).

**Edit:**

As @TonyK mentioned, this is not rigorously specified. If anyone has ideas on that, let me know. Intuitively, I think it might have something to do with curve length.

Take a curve formed in from points in the normal-binormal planes associated with each point on the primary curve so the each point on the curve is equidistant from, and arbitrarily close to the primary curve with respect to the normal-binormal plane it lies in. It might be the case that if you have two such curves, A and B, if A is shorter than B, A can't make more full revolutions around the primary curve than B.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "number of revolutions"? The more I think about it, the harder it is to define! You can't just say "the number of times it rotates around the curve", because the curve isn't straight.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for the response. You're right: it is underspecified. It is possible that there is no reasonable way to define such an idea. But intuitively, I've been able to count the revolutions by hand in at least some cases. I'm trying to come up with a good definition, but it is difficult for me. I'll update the question with some thoughts and clarifications. If you have any ideas, I'm all ears :-)

Comment: And it's not just ill-defined, it's _ill-conditioned_. Arbitrarily small perturbation of the curve can cause arbitrarily large changes in the number of revolutions $-$ for instance, if your curve develops a helical perturbation, no matter how small, it will cause the normal to revolve $360^{\circ}$ for each turn of the helix.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Is it possible that a solution would be able to account for a non-finite number of revolutions? I'd be perfectly happy to have something that broke down for degenerate cases such as a helix with an infinite number of spirals, as long as the breakdown was apparent. Alternately, perhaps there is a class of curves for which this would make sense?

Comment: Another thought is the case where the curve is approximated by line segments. Then for each segment, you could perhaps determine the total change in angle of the normal relative to the segment for the portion of the curve approximated by that segment?

Comment: It seems that this is just not a useful metric! It is ill-defined and/or ill-conditioned. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: You can make this question well-defined by first restricting to curves whose normals are never zero, allowing you to define a *unit* normal everywhere, and assuming this unit normal is a *continuous* map into the unit sphere. Select two points on the unit sphere not in the image of that map. Use (say) a stereographic projection based at one of them to project the curve into the plane. *Define* the number of "revolutions" to be the winding number of the (projected) unit normal around the second point.

Comment: @whuber clever idea, but I tried it out, and depending on the points chosen I get different values.

Comment: @TonyK I have an idea for a knot invariant that depends on this. Though I may have just shuffled the complexity into an ill-defined, ill-conditioned question. Still, if this can be addressed, I'd be very happy.

Comment: That is correct, which is why I claimed your question is not well-defined!  It only becomes so once you fix a pair of points on the sphere once and for all.